# integrating Play with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, playframework

I want to use play with eclipse IDE, I found the instructions on Play website, [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/IDE#eclipse). However, I don't know where to add the following since this my first time to add plugins to eclipse this way!:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

Or where to run this:

```
// Compile the project before generating Eclipse files, so that generated .scala or .class files for views and routes are present
    EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)
```

**EDIT**
I added a file under my project directory called "plugins.sbt" and it contains:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-sbt" % "scripted-plugin" % sbtVersion.value

addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "0.8.5")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.3.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

After that I ran this command from my project directory which starts the interactive mode:

```
$ sbt
```

Then I ran `compile` in the interactive mode, but I'm getting the following error (the last 3 lines) that I really can't understand since I'm a beginner in such development environments!

```
> compile
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/Reem/Music/artest-engine/}artest-engine...
[info] Resolving com.github.gseitz#sbt-release;0.8.5 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.github.gseitz#sbt-release;0.8.5
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Reem\.ivy2\local\com.github.gseitz\sbt-release\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\0.8.5\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/gseitz/sbt-release_2.10_0.13/0.8.5/sbt-release-0.8.5.pom
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Reem\Music\activator-dist-1.3.10\repository\com.github.gseitz\sbt-release\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\0.8.5\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Reem\.activator\repository\com.github.gseitz\sbt-release\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\0.8.5\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/github/gseitz/sbt-release_2.10_0.13/0.8.5/sbt-release-0.8.5.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.github.gseitz/sbt-release/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-scalariform;1.3.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-scalariform;1.3.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Reem\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.sbt\sbt-scalariform\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\1.3.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-scalariform_2.10_0.13/1.3.0/sbt-scalariform-1.3.0.pom
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Reem\Music\activator-dist-1.3.10\repository\com.typesafe.sbt\sbt-scalariform\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\1.3.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Reem\.activator\repository\com.typesafe.sbt\sbt-scalariform\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\1.3.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-scalariform_2.10_0.13/1.3.0/sbt-scalariform-1.3.0.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-scalariform/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.3.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.gseitz#sbt-release;0.8.5: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-scalariform;1.3.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.github.gseitz:sbt-release:0.8.5 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]          com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-scalariform:1.3.0 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.github.gseitz:sbt-release:0.8.5 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (C:\Users\Reem\Music\artest-engine\plugins.sbt#L3-4)
[warn]            +- default:artest-engine_2.10:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn]          com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-scalariform:1.3.0 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (C:\Users\Reem\Music\artest-engine\plugins.sbt#L5-6)
[warn]            +- default:artest-engine_2.10:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.gseitz#sbt-release;0.8.5: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-scalariform;1.3.0: not found
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Aug 14, 2016 10:41:43 PM
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add all plugins in

```
cat  project/plugins.sbt 
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.2")

// eclipse plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

If you are using activator, then run 
activator compile
activator eclipse

For particular error (sbt-release), you may need to use lastest version.

When I checked my project, I am not referencing sbt-release plugin, you can try removing plugin and hit compile again.

Regards
Pari

Answer (score 0):

You can find the guidance [here](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/06/setting-eclipse-ide-play-development.html)